# How to get public certificate info of a mongod instance

Tags: ssl, mongodb

In a procedure to auto-renew the certificate with Let's Encrypt of a MongoDB instance, I want to know the specific certificate that the instance is serving.

Is there a way to get, for example, the expiry date or any other info?

Comment: You can check the certificate details of your instance through your browser quite easily.please check this article for more reference https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/how-to-view-ssl-certificate-details

Comment: Is a mongodb connection not a webpage.

Comment: @asmath if you complete your answer in the form of an answer and not a comment I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [little python3 program](https://github.com/2ion/certcheck) that does exactly what you asked for (with OpenSSL):

```
$ certcheck www.example.com:443 serverfault.com
 Host (SNI)      | Port | Crt Issuer    | Delta to expiry           | Status 
-----------------+------+---------------+---------------------------+--------
 www.example.com | 443  | DigiCert Inc  | 213 days, 23:50:03.267476 | VALID
 serverfault.com | 443  | Let's Encrypt | 80 days, 13:04:26.637472  | VALID
```

Note that `certcheck` accepts a list of hosts to check, you'd need to script that with OpenSSL.

With just OpenSSL, sed and bash:

```
$ openssl s_client \
  -servername www.example.com \
  -connect www.example.com:443 2>&1 < /dev/null \
| sed -nre '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/p' \
| openssl x509 -in - -enddate -noout
notAfter=Dec 25 23:59:59 2021 GMT
```

From `man x509`:

```
-enddate
    Prints out the expiry date of the certificate, that is the notAfter date.

-dates
    Prints out the start and expiry dates of a certificate.

-checkend arg
    Checks if the certificate expires within the next arg seconds and exits nonzero if yes it will expire or zero if not.
```

Replace `www.example.com:443` with `<your_mongodb_host>:27015`.

Comment: Just a note. Default port of mongodb is 27017.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the certificate details of your instance through your browser quite easily.please check this article for more reference
[Check SSL certificates in your browser](https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/how-to-view-ssl-certificate-details)

You can also use this command to check the certificates serving by this mongodb instance from client side:

> openssl s_client -showcerts -connect **instance-name**:**port-no**

Comment: Please add more detail for getting the bounty. The answer is not complete.

Comment: You probably don't want `443` on the end, you'll want the mongo port number (probably `27017`)

Comment: @hardillb thanks correct the same

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all Let's Encrypt certificates including their expiry dates with

```
certbot certificates
```

You could also try to script an auto renewal using

```
certbot renew
```

and then concatenate the newly obtained `fullchain` and `privkey` files to one pem file and save it where mongodb expects it to be. A script for doing this can be found here: https://gist.github.com/zabirauf/bda54230ca1335c1cf00e3adba682ee7

Comment: No sorry my request is to read the actual certificate served by mongo. The way you wrote showed  how to get the certificate from certbot that not necessarily is the same served by mongo. I want to check it directly from a mongo connection.